# Is it possible to have code review workflows in Bluemix Devops Services?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

We are used to running Java development projects, typically using Atlassian products including Stash. We're now trying to use Bluemix Devops Services instead.

One limitation we have found is that you cannot create Pull Requests, meaning we can't review changes to source code before it is merged.

Is this the case? And what do others do for source code review workflow in Bluemix Devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time no you can not do code reviews through Bluemix.  You can however attached the DevOps pipeline to a Github project though.